# What is a tree graft point?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I've heard some terminology in regards to trees that I haven't heard before.  There are some references to graft points in our code base in relation to n-ary trees.  What exactly is a graft point in a tree and what could these references be referring to?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A graft point is nothing more than the location of the node where you're tacking on/inserting an additional node or set of nodes. These can be new nodes or nodes you may have moved from some other location (For instance, when you're balancing a tree).

Answer (score 2):

I assume it's referring to something involving either http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grafting_%28computer%29 or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grafting_%28algorithm%29.